# How can I pass in a list of strings to dapper to select values from

Tags: c#, sql-server, dapper

I would like to us dapper to pass in a list of id's and build a select statement like

```
SELECT Id FROM (VALUES
('2f1a5d4b-008a-496e-b0cf-ba8b53224247'),
('bf63102b-0244-4c9d-89ae-bdd7b41f135c')) AS tenantWithFile(Id)
WHERE   NOT exists( SELECT [Id]

  FROM [dbo].[TenantDetail]AS td
  WHERE td.Id = tenantWithFile.Id
)
```

where I get back the items in the list that are not in the database.  Is there a simple way to do this with out making a type for TVP?

Comment: You would have to pass in a delimited string and then use dynamic sql  or parse that string. A TVP is a much easier and performant solution. What is wrong with that approach?

Comment: @SeanLange my issue with TVP is having to create a type while the query is running.  I was looking for a way to setup a Table Variable but that doesn't seem to be an option either.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "create a type while the query is running".

Comment: TVP needs a table type defined correct?

Comment: That is correct. You have to define the table type before you can send it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As Sean mentioned,  here is a little snippet which demonstrates how you can parse a delimited string without a TVF.   ... easily incorporated into your query.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourList varchar(max)='2f1a5d4b-008a-496e-b0cf-ba8b53224247,bf63102b-0244-4c9d-89ae-bdd7b41f135c'

Select Id = xmlnode.n.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')
 From  (values (cast('<x>' + replace(@YourList,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml))) xmldata(xd)
 Cross Apply xd.nodes('x') xmlnode(n)
```

**Returns**

```
Id
2f1a5d4b-008a-496e-b0cf-ba8b53224247
bf63102b-0244-4c9d-89ae-bdd7b41f135c
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure SQL or SQL Server 2016+, you could just pass a JSON array and then use OPENJSON to turn to array into a table

```
DECLARE @j AS NVARCHAR(max) = '["2f1a5d4b-008a-496e-b0cf-ba8b53224247", "bf63102b-0244-4c9d-89ae-bdd7b41f135c"]';
SELECT [value] FROM OPENJSON(@j)
```